# Mac List of ASN1 OIDs and Translations

Tags: macos, certificate, asn.1

I'm looking for a canonical list of all the OIDs used by Apple's certificate QuickLook viewer, together with their displayed names.

Ideally in English and all the other languages. Certainly there must be some sort of strings file containing these.

For example:

```
"2.5.4.3" = "Common Name";
"2.5.4.6" = "Country Name";
"2.5.4.7" = "Locality Name";
"2.5.4.8" = "State of Province Name";
"2.5.4.9" = "Street Address";
"2.5.4.10" = "Organization Name";
"2.5.4.11" = "Organizational Unit Name";
"2.5.4.13" = "Description";
"2.5.4.17" = "Postal Code";

"1.2.840.113549.1.1.1" = "RSA Encryption";
"1.2.840.113549.1.1.4" = "MD5 with RSA Encryption";
"1.2.840.113549.1.1.5" = "SHA-1 with RSA Encryption";

"1.2.840.113549.1.9.1" = "E-Mail Addresse";


"1.2.840.113635.100.4.7" = "Apple ID Sharing Certificate";

"1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2" = "Apple Developer Certificate (Development)";
"1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.4" = "Apple Developer Certificate (Submission)";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The raw strings are found in the following file:

/System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/English.lproj/OID.strings

Note that on my system (OS X 10.8.3), this file was a binary-encoded .strings file rather than the usual UTF-16 type. To view it, you'll likely need to convert it using `plutil`:

```
plutil -convert xml1 -o ~/Desktop/OIDXML.strings \
/System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/English.lproj/OID.strings
```

While those are the end-product, Apple also provides developers with the strings from all the localized resources within OS X in the form of AppleGlot Glossaries available for download from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=localization.

For each of the 30 or so languages, there are around 500 or so AppleGlot `.lg` glossaries for each localizable product. The one you'll want is `SecurityFoundation.12A269.<language code>.lg`, where `<language code>` is an abbreviation for the language (for example, `E` for Spanish, `D` for German, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

OID are not registered centrally, instead an organization can get ownership of a node and assign new OIDs below that node. It is therefore difficult to get a full list of assigned OIDs.

However, there are some databases collecting large numbers of OIDs for example:
[OID repository](http://www.oid-info.com/)